# Replacing a query string if already present using JavaScript in a Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've written a Chrome extension with the aim that on button click the correct query string will be appended to the current url. For example: '?wcmmode=edit'.

It works to an extent, however it appends multiples as shown in the screenshot if the query strong already exists and it's clicked again or one of the other three query strings are clicked.

I have four buttons appending a very similar query string as follows, but these shouldn't append as a second query string with '&'. They should clear the previous one first.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNwCq.png)

```
// Disabled Mode
function handler_one() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        currentWindow: true,
        active: true
    }, function(tab) {
        const customParam = 'wcmmode=disabled';
        const url = tab[0].url
        const hashStart = (url.indexOf('#') === -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf('#');
        const querySymbol = (url.indexOf('?') === -1) ? '?' : '&';
        const newUrl = url.substring(0, hashStart) + querySymbol + customParam + url.substring(hashStart);
        chrome.tabs.update(undefined, {
            url: newUrl
        });
    });
};
// WCM Mode Edit
function handler_two() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        currentWindow: true,
        active: true
    }, function(tab) {
        const customParam = 'wcmmode=edit';
        const url = tab[0].url
        const hashStart = (url.indexOf('#') === -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf('#');
        const querySymbol = (url.indexOf('?') === -1) ? '?' : '&';
        const newUrl = url.substring(0, hashStart) + querySymbol + customParam + url.substring(hashStart);
        chrome.tabs.update(undefined, {
            url: newUrl
        });
    });
};
// WCM Mode Design
function handler_three() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        currentWindow: true,
        active: true
    }, function(tab) {
        const customParam = 'wcmmode=design';
        const url = tab[0].url
        const hashStart = (url.indexOf('#') === -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf('#');
        const querySymbol = (url.indexOf('?') === -1) ? '?' : '&';
        const newUrl = url.substring(0, hashStart) + querySymbol + customParam + url.substring(hashStart);
        chrome.tabs.update(undefined, {
            url: newUrl
        });
    });
};
// WCM Mode Preview
function handler_four() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        currentWindow: true,
        active: true
    }, function(tab) {
        const customParam = 'wcmmode=preview';
        const url = tab[0].url
        const hashStart = (url.indexOf('#') === -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf('#');
        const querySymbol = (url.indexOf('?') === -1) ? '?' : '&';
        const newUrl = url.substring(0, hashStart) + querySymbol + customParam + url.substring(hashStart);
        chrome.tabs.update(undefined, {
            url: newUrl
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if the string already exists before appending.

```
if ( url.indexOf(customParam) > 0 ) ...
```

or

```
if ( url.searchParams.get(customParam) ) { 
    alert('already exists'); 
}
```